# Dispatching drag-end event

Tags: javascript, d3.js, event-dispatching

I want to programmatically fire the "end" event of d3-drag.
I have some circles and have the drag-handling of them implemented like so:

```
...
.call(d3.drag()
     .on("drag", function () {...})
     .on("end", function () {...})
)
```

Now, later in my code, I would like to trigger the "end" part of this programmatically.

I have already tried something like this:

```
d3.select("#myID").dispatch("end");
d3.select("#myID").dispatch("dragend");
d3.select("#myID").call(d3.drag().dispatch("end"));
```

Comment: Do you need to pass any specific event information to the function, or does it just need to run on a specified selection?

Comment: The function runs on the selection of those circles and uses "this" to reference the dragged circle and the data/position of the circle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to generate any actual event data, and I understand the question correctly, you can do this relatively easily without d3.dispatch directly. The below will give you `this` and the node data itself (in d3v5 it will also give you `i` and `nodes`).

D3v5 and earlier

In d3v5 and earlier, the signatures for a function passed to `selection.each()` and `drag.on()` were the same. In this case you can easily assign the function to a variable and pass it to both. Alternatively, you could access the drag event function with `drag.on("typeName")`.

Here's a quick example:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",500)
  .attr("height",300);
  
var data = [{x:40,y:100},{x:250,y:100}];

var circles = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 10)
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
  .attr("fill", function(d,i) {
    return ["steelblue","crimson"][i]
  })

var drag = d3.drag()
  .on("drag", function(d) {
    d.x = d3.event.x; d.y = d3.event.y;
    d3.select(this)
      .attr("cx", d.x)
      .attr("cy", d.y);
  })
  .on("end", function(d) {
     console.log(d.x+","+d.y);
     d3.select(this)
       .transition()
       .attr("r", 30)
       .transition()
       .attr("r", 10);
  })
  
circles.call(drag);

d3.select("button").on("click", function() {
  var circle = d3.select("circle")
    .each(drag.on("end"));
})
```

```css
circle {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<button>Trigger Drag End On Blue Circle</button>
```

D3v6

In d3v6 the signatures of functions passed to `selection.each()` and `drag.on()` are different. The datum is the first parameter of the former and the second parameter of the latter. So we could use Function.apply() within `selection.each()` to trigger the end function and pass the proper `this` and `d` while passing `null` for the event data.

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",500)
  .attr("height",300);
  
var data = [{x:40,y:100},{x:250,y:100}];

var circles = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 10)
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
  .attr("fill", function(d,i) {
    return ["steelblue","crimson"][i]
  })

var drag = d3.drag()
  .on("drag", drag)
  .on("end", dragend)

circles.call(drag);

d3.select("button").on("click", function() {
   var circle = d3.select("circle")
    .each(function(d) { 
       dragend.apply(this,[null,d]) 
    })
})


function dragend(event,d) {
  console.log(d.x+","+d.y);
  d3.select(this)
    .transition()
    .attr("r", 30)
    .transition()
    .attr("r", 10);
}
function drag(event,d) {
  d.x = event.x; d.y = event.y;
  d3.select(this)
    .attr("cx", d.x)
    .attr("cy", d.y);
}
```

```css
circle {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<button>Trigger Drag End On Blue Circle</button>
```

Comment: And what if I need to access event data? I tried all possible solutions mentioned here and in other posts, but with no luck :-/ My selection calls select(#element).call(drag.drag()..) on which event handlers are registered, so seems like that is an obstacle while dispatching